# Failed dependencies: libcurl.so.4(CURL_OPENSSL_3)(64bit)

Tags: libraries, centos, synergy

I'm trying to install Synergy in my CentOS 6.5, here's what happens:

```
# rpm -ivh ./synergy-1.4.16-r1969-Linux-x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
```

> libcurl.so.4(CURL_OPENSSL_3)(64bit) is needed by synergy-1.4.16-1.x86_64

And I have this `libcurl` package:

```
# rpm -qa |grep libcurl
libcurl-7.19.7-37.el6_4.x86_64
```

I've installed CentOS today, it's my first day using Linux.

Comment: Where did you get this synergy RPM? Often there are different distros which package up software that use various versions of "libcurl". You're likely butting into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `rpm -q --provides libcurl` you can see what your libcurl package provides. If you run `rpm -qp --requires synergy-1.4.16-r1969-Linux-x86_64.rpm` you can see what your synergy rpm requires.

The problem appears to be synergy was built against a libcurl package that provides `libcurl.so.4(CURL_OPENSSL_3)(64bit)` which the normal libcurl that comes with CentOS doesn't have. To resolve this you've got a few options

1. Find the libcurl RPM that provides `libcurl.so.4(CURL_OPENSSL_3)(64bit)`. I haven't been able to find it with some quick searches.
2. Contact synergy and ask them about this.
3. Assuming you have all the other dependencies, you could install the RPM with nodeps (`rpm -ivh --nodeps synergy-1.4.16-r1969-Linux-x86_64.rpm`) and it will probably work fine.

A few tips that won't solve your problem but will be useful to debug stuff

- You can do yum searches for libraries by doing `yum whatprovides 'libcurl.so.4()(64bit)'`
- You should use `yum install` or `yum localinstall` when installing standalone RPMs since it will resolve dependencies for you. It wouldn't have helped in this case but could in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Synergy bug filed about this issue. http://synergy-foss.org/spit/issues/details/3919/#

Comment: As this bug mentions, the simplest fix to all of this is to install the older version 1.4.15 instead of this buggy 1.4.16: http://synergy-foss.org/download/?file=synergy-1.4.15-Linux-x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 0):

Oh no, some files of `curl` are in `openssl` or `gnutls` package,  those doens't related to `curl` package. please innstall `openssl` or `gnutls`.

Comment: Both are installed already!

Package openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.4.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do   ////// Package gnutls-2.8.5-10.el6_4.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: after this message, i curl/types.h if i no made mistake, and comment some header files. but your case is binary files.

Comment: oh by the way, please install openssl development package.